# Index of a dynamic created list Javascript

Tags: javascript, list, dynamic, indexing

i have a dynamically created list with data of a json.
So my question is how to get the index of a clicked item.

I tried this:

```
$("li").click(function() {
       var index = $("li").index(this);
       alert(index); });
```

But this didnt work. I dont get an alert? 
If i create some static Li elements, i get the index of them.

Please help me :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically created lists will require delegated events...

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
       var index = $(this).index();
       alert(index);
});
```

If the `<ul>` is also dynamically created, please select a parent node that exists before the list is created.

Comment: Works great :)) U help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: @user2561004 if you are satisfied with this answer, please mark it appropriately. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. You just want `$(this).index()`:

   ```
   $("li").click(function() {
      var index = $(this).index();
      alert(index); });
   ```

   From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index):

   > If no argument is passed to the `.index()` method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.
2. When you do `$("li").click(...)`, it hooks it up to the elements that exist *at that point in time*. Ones you add later won't get the click handler assigned to them. The best way to approach dynamic lists like this is usually *event delegation*. DevlshOne gives you an example [in his/her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17550486/157247). The basic idea is this:

   ```
   $("selector for the list, not the list items").on("click", "li", function() {
       // handler code here
   });
   ```

   That hooks `click` on the *list*, not the list items, but then fires the handler when the click occurs as though you had hooked click on the handler.

Comment: His problem is directly related to the dynamic creation of the LI items, not the value of index.

Comment: His post contains the statement **But this didnt work. I dont get an alert? If i create some static Li elements, i get the index of them.**

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. assuming that `ul` is not loaded dynamicaly.

```
$("ul.containerclass").on("click", "li", function() 
{
   var index = $(this).index();
   alert(index);
});
```

or

```
$(document).on("click", ".containerclass li", function() {
   var index = $(this).index();
   alert(index);
});
```

Note : here containerclass can be ID

Answer (score -1):

It is

```
$("li").click(function() {
       var index = $(this).index();
       alert(index);
});
```

Comment: His problem is directly related to the dynamic creation of the LI items, not the value of index.

Comment: How could anyone guess that? I do not recomend live events as the default solution to any problem and there is more than one way to add handlers to dynamically created lists.

Comment: His post contains the statement **But this didnt work. I dont get an alert? If i create some static Li elements, i get the index of them.** No guessing involved.